# Using noUiSlider, how do I change the outputted number into a input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit new to JavaScript, so forgive me if this question is pretty basic. I've been playing with the plugin so far and love it, it's great for a CSS guy to manipulate the style. I've been able to connect the slider to an input using serialization without any issue. The following is what I haven't been able to figure out, not really sure the code I should write.

I want to have a slider with 20 points (-20 and +20). When a user chooses one of these points I will convert this number to a percentage and multiply it by a variable loaded from the server. Essentially the math would look like this:

```
Code: (1 + ({.sliderPosition} / 100)) * {.serverVariable} = {.inputValue}   
Example: (1 + (15 / 100)) * 52.00 = 59.80
```

Thank you for your help, let me know if there is anything I should clarify.

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YyHGq/4/

Comment: create a jsfiddle with you example

Comment: jfiddle uri - http://jsfiddle.net/YyHGq/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure out the solution and added it to the jsfiddle.

```
$.fn.writeFromServer = function (value) {
    this.val("$" + ((1 + (value / 100)) * 52).toFixed(2));
};

$(function () {
    $("#slider").noUiSlider({
        range: [-20, 20],
        direction: "ltr",
        start: 0,
        step: 1,
        handles: 1,
        behaviour: "tap",
        serialization: {
            to: [$('.value'), 'writeFromServer'],
        }
    });
});
```